# Is there an efficient way to round a float to the nearest hundredths place in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to round a float in swift but everything I have found tells you to convert it in a string. Is there a way to convert the float itself?

Example: 14.14910001 -> 14.15

Comment: I don't see a reason to except for display purposes.  That's why the only examples you are finding is for converting to a string.

Answer (score 11):

You can use `round()` with a "scale factor" of 100:

```
let x = 14.14910001
let y = round(100.0 * x) / 100.0
println(y) // 14.15
```

But you should note that a binary floating number *cannot*
represent a number like 14.15 exactly, so this will give the nearest
`Double` approximation of 14.15.

Comment: Of course, one needs to keep in mind that when that value is displayed it might print out as 14.1499999998.

Comment: @HotLicks: You are right, that's why I added the additional statement.